# ninja depfile has multiple output paths when build flutter to android app

Tags: android, flutter, ninja

Today after I run flutter clean and rebuild the [flutter app](https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/flutter-netease-music) to android apk in MacBook Pro with M1 pro chip, shows error like this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':system_clock:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/bin/ninja with arguments {-C /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.pub-cache/hosted/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn%47dart-pub%47/system_clock-1.2.0/android/.cxx/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a systemclock}
  ninja: Entering directory `/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.pub-cache/hosted/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn%47dart-pub%47/system_clock-1.2.0/android/.cxx/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a'
  [1/2] Building CXX object 'CMakeFiles/systemclock.dir/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.pub-cache/hosted/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn%47dart-pub%47/system_clock-1.2.0/cpp/system_clock.cpp.o'
  FAILED: CMakeFiles/systemclock.dir/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.pub-cache/hosted/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn%47dart-pub%47/system_clock-1.2.0/cpp/system_clock.cpp.o 
  /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi16 --gcc-toolchain=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot  -Dsystemclock_EXPORTS -I/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.pub-cache/hosted/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn%47dart-pub%47/system_clock-1.2.0/android/src/main/cpp/../../../../cpp/include -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT 'CMakeFiles/systemclock.dir/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.pub-cache/hosted/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn%47dart-pub%47/system_clock-1.2.0/cpp/system_clock.cpp.o' -MF CMakeFiles/systemclock.dir/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.pub-cache/hosted/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn%47dart-pub%47/system_clock-1.2.0/cpp/system_clock.cpp.o.d -o 'CMakeFiles/systemclock.dir/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.pub-cache/hosted/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn%47dart-pub%47/system_clock-1.2.0/cpp/system_clock.cpp.o' -c '/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.pub-cache/hosted/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn%47dart-pub%47/system_clock-1.2.0/cpp/system_clock.cpp'
  depfile has multiple output paths
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

why did this happen? what should I do to fix it? this is the flutter doctor information:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.1, on macOS 12.2.1 21D62 darwin-arm, locale en-CN)
    • Flutter version 2.5.1 at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/fvm/versions/2.5.1
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision ffb2ecea52 (6 months ago), 2021-09-17 15:26:33 -0400
    • Engine revision b3af521a05
    • Dart version 2.14.2
    • Pub download mirror https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/dart-pub
    • Flutter download mirror https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/flutter

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application
      Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/211.7628.21.2111.8193401/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 13.2.1, Build version 13C100
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application
      Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/211.7628.21.2111.8193401/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application
      Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/211.7628.21.2111.8193401/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application
      Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/211.7628.21.2111.8139111/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.3.2)
    • IntelliJ at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Applications/JetBrains Toolbox/IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.3.2)
    • IntelliJ at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/213.6777.52/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.3.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/213.6461.79/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] VS Code (version 1.65.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.36.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-arm64  • Android 12 (API 32) (emulator)
    • macOS (desktop)             • macos         • darwin-arm64   • macOS 12.2.1 21D62 darwin-arm
    • Chrome (web)                • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 99.0.4844.51
```

I have tried to change the NDK version to 20.0.5594570, still did not fix this problem.

Comment: I think you should open an issue on Github.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue before specifically related to android.

And this might be useful and might not be, in my case it was because I had a %
sign in my project name, i.e Demo%20App/source/ instead of Demo_App, ninja does not like that, so if its the same in your case, be sure to remove the %, and it should solve the issue

see below link

[Error building : depfile has multiple output paths ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54569963/error-building-depfile-has-multiple-output-paths-ninja-build-stopped-subcomm)